About min, min7 and min9 chords
Saw vid by David Bennett which discussed songs that only use minor chord. There were songs that used min7 chords only. That got me thinking
Can’t min7 chord be technically considered major chord as they are major triad with a different root note? min7 doesnt sound as dark to me as the actual min chord
I feel that min9 is more minor sounding than min7 as min9 is formed by maj7 which is actually formed by a min triad with different root note.

A minor 7th chord is not a major chord. The interval between the root and the third determines whether a chord is major or minor. A minor 7th chord does however contain a major triad using the 3rd, 5th and 7th. For that matter a major 7th chord contains a minor triad also starting on the 3rd so your logic doesn’t really hold up.
Perhaps the reason a minor 7th doesn’t sound as dark as a minor triad to you is because it contains two pairs of 5ths, for example, A minor has A-E and C-G. 5ths have a consonant and bright sound.
I don’t get your last paragraph but major and minor 7th and 9th chords all contain alternating major and minor 3rd intervals:
Minor 9th: m3,M3,m3,M3 ex: A,C,E,G,B
Major 9th: M3,m3,M3,m3 ex: A,C#,E,G#,B
Another way to look at them is by the interval relationship to the root:
Minor 9th: m3,P5,m7,M9
Major 9th: M3,P5,M7,M9
If you notice they both contain the same number of major and minor 3rds but in a different order. The minor starts with a m3 and the major starts with a M3.They also share the same 5th and 9th.
The bottom line is that the way chords sound to you is at least partially subjective and not necessarily based in fact.

Not only does a minor 7th chord have two pairs of fifths, but one of the fifths brackets a major triad.  An AM7 chord, for example, has an A-E fifth bracketing an A-C-E minor triad, an a C-G fifth bracketing a C-E-G major triad.  A C major seventh chord has the aformementioned C-G fifth (C-E-G) and an E-B fifth bracketing an E-G-B minor triad.

Adding to John's nicely comprehensive answer - ACEG, called Am7, in a different guise, CEGA, becomes C6. The former will have a minor feel, especially with a good root A underneath, while the latter will feel like a major, again with a decent root C under.
Maybe that's what makes OP think the way they do?


Can’t min7 chord be technically considered major chord as they are major triad with a different root note?

In a way, yes. An example that comes up over and over is Am7 with a root of A versus C6 with a root of C where both chords contain the exact same pitch classes A C E G. How do you distinguish which is the "correct" chord root? By the harmonic context, which boils down to finding a plausible dominant for either chord. If, for example, there was an E7, then the A is a plausible root/tonic. If there was a G7, then the C is a plausible root/tonic.

min7 doesnt sound as dark to me as the actual min chord

I think it helps to continue the discussion with awareness of keys and diatonic chords, because traditional jazz harmony is based on key-based diatonic harmony.
Where are minor seventh chords found amongst the diatonic seventh chords? Are any of them in the tonic chord position? No. In major keys, they are unambiguously the ii, iii, and vi chords. In minor keys chords are less clearly defined, but if you consider a leading tone necessary to really get minor key harmony, the tonic chord is a minor-major seventh chord, not a plain diatonic minor seventh chord. The plain minor seventh chord will be only the iv7 chord, or perhaps the non-functional-minor-dominant chord v7.
What this hints at is minor seventh progressions, like for example, Em7 Am7 Dm7, suggest the modal harmonic regions of a key rather than the tonal regions of a key, which would give those chords functional identities of iii vi ii. In other words, in terms of tonality, they suggest a major key.
By contrast if you played minor key seventh chords and focused on the tonal harmonies, you might use something like Bm7b5 E7 Am(maj7). Notice how the rooted minor triad portion happens only on the tonic chord.
It may seem counter-intuitive, but the way to suggest minor key tonality is not necessarily to use all minor type chords.
All of the above comes with a big caveat: lots of music is made with a general minor mode feel that is not necessarily proper minor-key harmony. The essential difference is between what is proper major/minor key system harmony and other harmonic styles which for the purpose of this answer can be lumped together as "modal" harmony.

...min7 doesnt sound as dark to me as the actual min chord

My only purpose in this answer is an attempt to explain your perception of minor seventh chords as relatively less "dark" or perhaps less dramatically minor sounding that other chords. By the way, I agree with your perception and thing minor seventh chords have a relatively "soft" feel. They can be fairly mellow. Certain when comparing something like Dm7 Am7 to E7b9 Am(maj7). My explanation for that sense is, when considering the big picture of our listening experience, years of listening to music, when we hear minor seventh chords, they occur most commonly as the modal harmonies, iii7 vi7 ii7 of major keys, and therefore hint at a major tonality.
